# How can I make chrome always display the address bar? It autohides when I scroll and then I need to scroll back to show it

Tags: chrome-for-android

How can I make Chrome on Android always display the address bar? It autohides when I scroll and then I need to scroll back to show it.

Please. I have googled it for quite some time already.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: If you badly need it switch to Chrome versions before 27

Comment: i needed that too. i think that is bad politic of goigke, intentionaly removing bunch of iptions and user cant even customuze simple things in mobile chrome.

Comment: Definitely. Google sucks anyway. Linux rocks.

Answer (score 1):

No... It is not possible.

> The short answer is no. If you feel that this should be a feature then
>   please file a bug on crbug.com/new. :) Hope that answers your
>   question.

- [Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/lT8ZdfgGYDI/EF_nySikF1oJ)

Comment: Logic being ,  it  eats into screen real estate, if always displayed

Comment: Google is not a user friendly company. They always try to restrict users and push their Android scam product on users. I want real Linux on my smartphones and I want it now.

Comment: @Vesa That comment isn't relevant here... If you don't want Android, but want pure Linux on a mobile device buy an Ubuntu phone. The answer to your problem is then that you bought the wrong phone. https://www.ubuntu.com/mobile/devices